# For each multiple select insert values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form with multiple selects.
I want that for each user who is selected (checkbox), a value is inserted from the select (is multiple) in database

User1: 5,7,8
User2: 6,4
User3: 4

*For User1*: 3 rows inserted
*For user2*: 2 rows inserted
*For user3*: 1 single row
*Total*: 6 rows inserted

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" value="<?=$row['id'];?>">
    <label for="<?=$row['id'];?>"><?=$row['username'];?></label>
    <select id="<?=$row['id'];?>" type="tel" step="0.01" name="nota[<?=$row['id'];?>]" value="" multiple style="-wap-input-format: 'N'">
        <option value="">chose</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I Use MYSQL.
Ho to make for each checkbox to insert values from select(in pears)?
insert values from select1 to checkbox1, no from select2 to checkbox1.

Comment: Great. And the question is? And where can we find your code?

Comment: While we wait for clarification on your question, you're assigning the same id to your `checkbox` and your `select` for each row. Each id should really be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, assuming you're using PDO as the database API. If not, you can easily translate it to other APIs.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (id, option) VALUES (:id, :option)";
foreach ($_POST['boxes'] as $id) {
    foreach($_POST['nota'][$id] as $option) {
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':option' => $option));
    }
}
```